# MYSQL trigger gets deleted automatically

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have using mysql 5.1 with cpanel /whm centOS.

I had to use trigger for one of my website. so i installed trigger as root so that when something gets inserted on one table there some more rows gets inserted in other table

Everything was working fine, but i have seen that there is no trigger in my dtabase.

How does that be deleted from DB.

I am bit worried because currently site is not live , but it can cause problem if this happens in live site.

Does any mysql updation cause the trigger to delete. but i have no updated.

How can i make sure it don't happen in future

Thanks

Comment: What tool are you using to add the trigger ? Maybe ... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52587

Comment: I used phpmyadmin as root user using sql query. everything was working as required before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

Comment: It is showing empty result set .
i tried going in information_schema -- triggers and that's table is empty.